# The over-determinant nature for multibody problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, many-body

For an multibody system with N point particles, in Newtonian frame, to solve for the N positions of each particle as a function of time:

- There is 1 equation for the center of mass.
- There are $\frac{N(N-1)}{2}$ force functions between each pair of particles.

So there are $\frac{N(N-1)}{2} + 1$ constraint equations for N variables, which is soluble when $N=2$ but over-deterministic when $N \ge 3$.  What is wrong with my argument?

Answer (score 3):

Forces aren't the same as constraints. You can have as many forces as you want acting on a single particle, and you still only get one second order ODE out of it.

To fully determine a system of $N$ second-order ODEs, one needs:

- $N$ initial conditions for the positions.
- $N$ initial conditions for the velocities.
- $N$ second order equations of motion.

For the n-body problem, we have the force formula (the force of particle $j$ acting on particle $i$): $$F_{ij}=Gm_im_j\frac{\vec{x}_j-\vec{x}_i}{\|\vec{x}_j-\vec{x}_i\|^3}$$

The $N$ equations of motion are then:

$$m_i \ddot{x}_i=\sum_{j\neq i} F_{ij}$$

There are $N$ choose 2 forces involved, yeah, but we still only have $3N$ equations of motion for $3N$ variables (in 3 dimensions), so isn't overdetermined at all.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good answer